# Windows 2008, 2 NICS, routing problem

Tags: windows-server-2008, routing, nic

I've some questions regarding basic routing, can't seem to relate to other questions posted in this site.

My architecture:
Windows 2008 server with 2 nics in the server.

NIC1:
IP 10.198.6.xxx, submask 255.255.252.0, gateway 10.198.4.xxx

NIC2:
IP 192.168.168.xxx, submask 255.255.255, no gateway defined

both NICS are just connected to two separate switches, with other computers.

I want to be able that all the requests that have a destination of 192.168.168.xxx are redirected to the NIC2, all the other to the NIC1.

I know it's possible to do it with the route command, but normally we have to specify a gateway? (route ADD 192.168.168.0 MASK 255.255.255.0 ???)

How can this be archived?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have nearly same setup on my windows machines, Windows routes it automaticly, did you encounter any kind of problem while reaching other machines ?

And if you use "route print" you should see something like

```
0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0            10.198.6.zzz     10.198.6.xxx   10

10.198.6.0       255.255.255.0      10.198.6.xxx     10.198.6.xxx   10
10.198.6.xxx     255.255.255.255    127.0.0.1        127.0.0.1      10
10.255.255.255   255.255.255.255    10.198.6.xxx     10.198.6.xxx   10

192.168.174.0    255.255.255.0      192.168.174.xxx  192.168.174.xxx    10
192.168.174.xxx  255.255.255.255    127.0.0.1        127.0.0.1      10
192.168.174.255  255.255.255.255    192.168.174.xxx  192.168.174.xxx    10
```

again, this from my route config out, it should look like simillar, not the same. The 0.0.0.0 route is the everything not defined and 10.186.6.zzz is the gateway.

Comment: It was not a configuration problem as you suggested. The problem was elsewhere (configuration of the ESX host itself).

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a routing protocol for it to route between interfaces. RIP will be the easiest to configure. [This guide](http://www.windowsnetworking.com/articles_tutorials/How-configure-Windows-2008-Server-IP-Routing.html) outlines the steps to take for that OS.